# Code coverage of play 1.2.7 project with jacoco

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x, jacoco

For my project I get a good coverage report by jacoco for the models, but no coverage is shown to the controllers. Is there any configuration option that needs to be applied to jacoco to cover the static methods in the play framework controllers?

This is the command line to launch the automated tests in play with jacoco:
$ play-1.2.7/play auto-test PWO -javaagent:../jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar

Comment: Are you sure the static methods are invoked by the tests?

Comment: I'm confident that the static methods are run: for once the test result changes when I alter the static methods; second when I set a breakpoint in a static method in Eclipse and run the internal junit tester with debug enabled, it halts during test execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with Jacoco, if you combine it with Mockito or Powermock. Maybe it is your case as well:

- Mockito - https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=385&q=jacoco
- Powermock - more than one issues. See https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/list?can=2&q=jacoco&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Milestone+Owner+Summary&cells=tiles

As far as I think, Jacoco has no problem with static methods or static initializers.